# On a proper skateboard, what is the proper level of freedom for the wheels to spin?

Tags: equipment, skateboarding, spin

I've just started my skateboarding story, and bought my first board online. It was not the cheapest one, but nothing fancy, because I don't feel like I need anything pricey to start.

It was a nice experience to skate for the first time, but I feel that my board's wheels aren't spinning like they should.

At what rate should spinning skateboard wheels decelerate, and how can this be determined?

Comment: I would think this is a fairly objective question for an expert.  This isn't "does my golf swing look right?", this is "is my 6 iron the proper length?"  Estimating the rotation may be a little subjective, but there is a right answer of how fast a wheel should spin.  That said, perhaps it requires a change to deter such subjective opinions...

Comment: Done.  It probably needs a bit more editing, as the wording is clunky, but you hopefully get the idea :-)  Seems a useful question, though I have no clue!

Comment: MyFantasy, perhaps add your video as a comment, as it's still may be useful to any experts who work more on experience or rules of thumb rather than exact measurements (as I'm guessing many do).  Though an exact answer is certainly appreciated to make the result more applicable to a wider range of people.

Comment: @MyFantasy512 could you please give me little more information about what you would like to know, i couldn't find anything till now and looks as if there is not much research on deceleration of wheels.

Comment: Hello, maybe you could be a bit more specific in your question. I also think your heading "On a proper skateboard, what is the proper level of freedom for the wheels to spin?" and the last line in your post "At what rate should spinning skateboard wheels decelerate, and how can this be determined?" isn't the same question. One point of the SE forums are that each questions contains just one question :) So in short, if could you clarify and write just one question it's more likely you can get a good answer.

Comment: There's a lot that goes into this: *abec* rating of the bearings, wheel diameter, and the amount of dust/dirt. 

Smaller wheels will get up to speed faster than big wheels, but will slow down quicker. 

The more dust/dirt in the area, the more that will get into the bearings, cause friction and slow down.

The more important thing to concentrate on is, how *smooth* the board is. If you're pushing more than you want, get a set of high-quality bearings like Bones Swiss or some abec 7s. Then you'll at least know what top notch bearings feel like and will have reference point for the future.